# Relations when entity belongs to same entity twice (JS-Data)

Tags: jsdata

Imagine a Sales Order model, like this:

```
create table sales_orders(
  id int primary key,
  order_date date,
  customer_party_id int not null references parties,
  sales_party_id int not null references parties
);

create table parties (
  id int primary key,
  type text check (type in 'individuals', 'organizations'),
  given_name text,
  surname text,
  org_name text
);
```

How to model JSData Relations in this case?

Obvious, I cannot do this:

```
store.defineMapper("sales_orders", {
    relations:{
        belongsTo:{
            parties:{
                foreignKey:"customer_party_id",
                localField:"customer_party"
            },
            parties:{
                foreignKey:"sales_party_id",
                localField:"sales_party"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I can rename one of the belongsTo fields, and that works on read, but not on write...(using JSONAPI adapter)

Comment: can you post your sales_party and your customer_party?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as an answer, but it's the only place I can put code.  :)  I'm not clear what's consuming the object you're sending but I would expect you to be able pass your parties as an array like the following:

```
store.defineMapper("sales_orders", {
relations:{
    belongsTo:{
        parties:[{
            foreignKey:"customer_party_id",
            localField:"customer_party"
        },
        {
            foreignKey:"sales_party_id",
            localField:"sales_party"
        }]
    }
}
```

});

Is this an option?

Comment: I didn't run anything.  I just suspect that if you want multiple parties and it's breaking because you're duplicating keys that it would allow you to send a list somehow.  That doesn't mean it will or that it will the way I suggest.  It depends on the service.  This would just be a typical way to handle multiple party objects in standard Object notation.

Answer (score 0):

ok so why do you want two foreign keys when you have `type` on your parties table to distinct customer from sale? unless this column is for something else, so then you can just create one more ex. `party_type` for that purpose.

I would suggest you delete one of the columns, rename the remaining one to `party_id` and then you should defineMapper for both tables like this

```
store.defineMapper('parties', {
    relations: {
        hasMany: {
            sales_orders: {
                foreignKey: 'party_id',
                localField: 'party'
            }
        }
    }
});
store.defineMapper('sales_orders', {
    relations: {
        belongsTo: {
            parties: {
                foreignKey: 'party_id',
                localField: 'party'
            }
        }
    }
});
```